# Online Credit Card Payment Processing

Tags: paypal, google-checkout, payment-processing

Most of my clients require donation and shopping cart integration into their websites.  I have always used PayPal to run the transactions, but PayPal is a nightmare to work with.  I'm looking for an alternative company to handle the credit card processing.

I had looked into Amazon FPS, then realized that it requires an Amazon account in order to process the transaction, which I cannot do.  Seems like my only option is Google Checkout.  Is it solid?  I've read some horror stories of random account closures.

Your thoughts would be helpful as I make this decision.  I am looking for ease of API integration, no requirements for the users other than valid credit-card information, and low transaction fees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try authorize.net.

Answer (score 3):

I've written modules to work with point Link Point and Authorize.net.  Authorize.net is far superior in consistency, logical response values, and had much better documentation.